# Проблема в создании запроса к БД

Tags: mysql

В БД `MySQL` есть таблица. Там есть столбец `X`. В столбце есть текст на кириллице, и в конце устанавливается всегда `</br>`. Какой можно сделать запрос для БД, чтоб он удалил все тэги в `</br>` в столбце `Х` ?

Comment: А что устанавливается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table set X = replace(X,'$','')
```

где $ символ или набор символов которые надо заменить/удалить.